# Git ignore all folders apart from

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to ignore all the files in my folder structure apart from the following conditions:

```
profiles (and all folders/files recursive)  
sites/xxx (and all folders/files recursive)
```

Currently my gitignore file looks like:

```
`*`  
!sites/xxx  
!sites/xxx/modules  
!sites/xxx/modules/*  
!profiles  
!profiles/xxx  
!profiles/xxx/*
```

This doesn't allow me to track sites/xxx/modules/new though, is there anyway round this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without looking at the manual, I have a vague memory that `.gitignore` is processed in order, and so the `!` lines should come before `*`.